# Java Help - With outputting the right format

Tags: java

New to programming so still grasping basic aspects, but have been able to write this so far:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("Path://pay.txt"));

    String name;
    int price;
    int quantity;
    int total;

    while(sc.hasNext()){
        name = sc.next();
        price = sc.nextInt();
        quantity = sc.nextInt();

        total = price * quantity;


        System.out.println(name + " : " + total);
    }
    sc.close();

}
```

**Output:**

```
Emma : $16
Sofia : $8
Olivia : $70
Emma : $9
Emma : $9
Emma : $4
Emma : $120
Sofia : $33
Emma : $78
Emma : $40
Sofia : $32
Olivia : $8
Sofia : $6
Olivia : $36
Emma : $9
Emma : $45
Emma : $54
Emma : $12
Emma : $78
Emma : $36
Olivia : $4
Emma : $64
Sofia : $42
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)
```

Instead of my output looking the way it does, where it shows the individual total sales for each line, I would like to output the total sale for each person....

```
  Income
  Emma: $xx
  Sofia: $yy
  Olivia: $zz
```

Could anyone help me out and guide me in the right direction? I feel like I'm close but not 100% sure.

Thanks for taking the time looking and reading this post.

Comment: One of two choices here: use a `HashMap<String, Double>` or create a class that holds a String and a double, and create an ArrayList of this type. Either way you go, you will need to sum the values as you collect them, and then print it all out at the end. I'm guessing that there's a streaming hack that will help with either.

Comment: "I feel like I'm close but not 100% sure." - Well, try what you think you should, and if it doesn't work, feel free to come back with a more specific question.

Comment: ... and no, you're not quite there yet.

Comment: That might be getting a little difficult if you're just starting. Basically what you need to do is go through all the results that were entered, and add up all the totals for each name. The easiest way to keep track of totals would probably be using one of Java's `Map` objects. Instead of printing after each entry though, you'll need to have them enter all the data, store the data in a list, then go through it and print. This question is pretty broad for the site though; this would be a better fit on a discussion medium like Google+ or Reddit.

Comment: You definitely need to go read up on at least arrays (which would provide a crude solution), but possibly also other basic data structures, to do this. My recommendation would be to follow some tutorial instead of trying to learn programming by starting with a task and trying to figure out the details of how to do it from there. Unless you already know of such data structures, in which case you should at least be able to come up with *some* idea of where to go from here.

Comment: Please edit your title to succinctly summarize the core issue of your Question.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, Thank you so much for the reply, I shall look into HashMap as I have never touched upon this either, if it isn't successful I shall try your second solution of creating classes and then an ArrayList (Going to have to re-read on them too)

Comment: @JoeC Don't know if there was need for that comment, I have clearly tried what I can. Just asking for info or where to look next to try and output the way I want to output, sorry

Comment: @Carcigenicate, Thank you also for your reply I shall take you advice and go and look up Map objects, Sorry about the broad question, didn't know how I could've worded it though. I shall have to look into one of the other two sites, thought this was a discussion side too? but I take it that it isn't.

Comment: @Dukeling Thank you too for your reply, will look into arrays too. As well as re-read or look at a tutorial on basic structures again. I thought I would need to put them into arrays but wasn't 100% sure :/

Comment: @Mr_M No, this site is for specific questions with specific, objective answers.

Comment: @BasilBourque Sorry that this question seems to broad but didn't know what else to put sorry, what would you of written? So that I can better label my questions in future. As I thought saying about the output was enough, but clearly not.

Comment: @Mr_M If you cannot write a succinct title, you are not yet ready to post on Stack Overflow. Work harder to understand your problem, do some googling/binging, and search Stack Overflow thoroughly before posting.

Answer (score 0):

Make an ArrayList for the names and another ArrayList for the total.
When you get a new input from the user, initially both arraylists are empty, you will add the name to the arraylist and add the total to the arraylist.
After that however , each time an input is entered, check if the name exists in the arraylist, if it doesn't add it, if it does, then get the index, and use that index in the total arraylist to retrieve the number and add the new value to it. Then after all the values are entered, loop through the arraylists and print them.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("Path://pay.txt"));
    ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<Integer> total = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    String name;
    int price;
    int quantity;


    while(sc.hasNext()){
        name = sc.next();

        price = sc.nextInt();
        quantity = sc.nextInt();

        if(names.contains(name)){
            int index = names.indexOf(name);
            int totalTemp = total.get(index);
            totalTemp += price * quantity;
            total.remove(index);
            total.add(totalTemp,index);
        }else{
            names.add(name);
            total.add(price*quantity);
        }
    }
    sc.close();
    for(int i=0;i<names.size();i++){
    System.out.println(names.get(i)+": "+total.get(i));
```

Comment: Or you can use the HashMap as mentioned by others.

Comment: parallel lists? ouch.